# How to customising zurb foundation top menu

Tags: html, css, menu, zurb-foundation

Can i do a zurb foundation menu like one show in example http://cssdeck.com/labs/soothing-css3-dropdown-animation

I am not sure how to create such Menu using zurb foundation.

Answer (score 1):

The site crashes my HTC one x so I couldn't sample what you want however as the name suggests "foundation" is just a base for you to build on so nothing is impossible. Infact just putting that css in your html making sure that it uses none of the same classes or ids would be sufficient.

EDIT

Managed to load it on my mobile to read the code. The first portion of css is just a normalizer so ignore that foundation comes with its own. Everything else should work fine except I would imagine you'll need to prefix the uls and lis with something to distinguish them from other such tags

Eg:

```
 .dropdown ul{
```